# C program crashes when I tried to set an element of type char* in my struct to a specific string?

Tags: c, struct, crash, malloc

I'm having a weird issue with my C program. I'm trying to keep track of the names and bonuses of weapons that I create in my little game, however, the program crashes after initializing a couple weapons.

This is my struct for weapons:

```
typedef struct weaponTag {
    char *name;
    int bonus;
} weaponNode;
```

Here I allocate enough memory for 6 different weapons to be made:

```
weaponNode *wep = malloc(sizeof(weaponNode) * 6);
initializeWeapons(&wep);
```

`initializeWeapons` is called using the address of the `wep` which was created right before:

```
void initializeWeapons(weaponNode **wep)
{
    printf("Initializing weapons...\n");
    setWeapon(wep[0], "Iron sword", 2);
    setWeapon(wep[1], "Steel sword", 4);
    setWeapon(wep[2], "Mithril sword", 7);
    setWeapon(wep[3], "Adamantine sword", 11);
    setWeapon(wep[4], "Dark Magic sword", 16);
    setWeapon(wep[5], "Diamond sword", 23);
}
```

I then call `setWeapon` for each weapon I want to create:

```
void setWeapon(weaponNode *wep, char *name, int bonus)
{
    wep->name = name;
    wep->bonus = bonus;
}
```

When I run this, it work for iron and steel swords, but then once it gets to the mithril sword, it gets stuck on `wep->name = name`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Pointer-to-pointer are not arrays. They are not 2D arrays. They are not pointers to arrays. They are not pointers to 2D arrays. Just get rid of the pointer-to-pointer and use a plain pointer to struct.

Comment: Yes I didn't see what Lundin says! ... You have to use `void initializeWeapons(weaponNode *wep)` and `setWeapon(wep[0], "Iron sword", 2);` have to be `setWeapon(wep+0, "Iron sword", 2); ` (or `setWeapon(&wep[0],"Iron sword", 2);` )

Comment: just a nit-pick: you do realize you're passing a `const char *` to `setWeapon`, right? you're not planning to modify the strings later on (or `free`'ing the `char *` member), because that won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a pointer to pointer to `weaponNode` to the `initializeWeapons` function, that's *almost* like passing an array of pointers, which is not what you have.

Change the `initializeWeapons` function to only take a pointer to the `weaponNode` structure, and when passing it on to e.g. `setWeapon` use either pointer arithmetic like `setWeapon(wep + 1, ...)` or use the address-of operator here like `setWeapon(&wep[1], ...)`.